# print_r() has been disabled for security reasons Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm Using codeigniter 3.1.6

`print_r()` has been disabled for security reasons this type of error regenerated so how to fixed it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow. Are you saying that CodeIgniter is complaining about your use of `print_r()`? It sounds like they consciously disabled it and this isn't something you want to "fix" within CodeIgniter; the concern would be within the PHP code base itself if that is the case, unless they're simply concerned about the idea behind `print_r()` in general

Comment: Switch hosting provider.

Comment: @vrajesh  If you are looking for debugging? use `var_dump()` function to debug.

Answer (score 1):

check the `disable_function` entry in the `php.ini` file, print_r is probably disabled there. Issue is most likely not related to Codeigniter.

if you have no access to php.ini file, you can check the configuration by using the `phpinfo()` from a Codeigniter Controller and see if the `print_r` function is disabled.